# minikube failed to start

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, minikube

Hello so i was using yesterday minikube and it was working fine but today i was trying to start with **minikube start** command and it give the following errors :[image: minikube start]

and after running **minikube status** it give the following result :[image: minikube status]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You do have corrupted data in one of te YAML files under *C:\Users\Tarik Ouhamou\.kube\config*

Comment: im new to this, and if that is the case how can i fix it please

Comment: Well we don't have access to your computer to see what's in those file, so this is hard to say. I am just rewording what the error message you are getting is telling you.

Comment: the file is just full of interrogation marks

Comment: You already had working cluster yesterday and today you wanted to start the same cluster again using the same command? If yes, you should delete this cluster `minikube delete` and then `minikube start --vm-driver=XXX`. When you are using `minkube start` it will create new VM. If you didn't delete cluster, it will be still there so there is no point to start it again. To sum up. Please remove minikube cluster and create it again. Let me know your output. If this won't help please provide more details based on [minikube docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/troubleshooting/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Exiting due to GUEST_START: Failed kubeconfig update: could not read config: Error decoding config from data control character are not allowed

and

> getting k8s client: client config: error loading config file "C:\Users<Your User>/.kube/config control characters are not allowed

Those errors indicates that your `$KUBECONFIG` has an invalid character in it.

#### Troubleshooting

For the future use, please provide more detailed information. It's well described in [Minikube Troubleshooting](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/troubleshooting/). The following commands might provide useful information for troubleshooting:

```
$ minikube logs
$ minikube start --alsologtostderr -v=2
$ kubectl config view
```

In minikube output there is also `updating the running virtualbox "minikube" VM` It might be related with network changes.

#### Possible Solution

- Remove config file from `C:\Users\<Your User>/.kube/` and start minikube again.
- Update your `Minikube` to newest version (current is 1.16).
- Recreate your minikube cluster using [minikube delete](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/delete/) and create new one.
- Execite `minikube update context`.

Comment: I've tried this and it is woking thank you very much for your help i really appreciate it.